# iOS photo gallery - flickr

Tags: iphone, ios, image, flickr, image-gallery

I'm working on an app for a client and the client wants absolutely everything to be shareable (using sharekit). One of the views that the client wants is a photo gallery that can be easily updated and viewed. I've looked around at folks who have done this and I particularly like the way the Obama 2012 app does it using flickr. This brings me to the question, I'm trying to use the flickr api to display a photo gallery that will allow sharekit to share the url to the image but am hitting a brick wall. I've searched for a few days now and haven't found a tutorial that shows a working example in the way I need it, if anyone has done something similar or knows a good tutorial that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, are you having issues with the Flickr API or with making a photo gallery in iOS? Those are two different beasts. You can retrieve a list of images using Flickr's API, but it's going to be a bit more work than that to mold it into a photo gallery.

Comment: if you are looking for a ready built photo gallery and imageviewer ala the facebook app or the photos app..try the Three20 API (Its the facebook api and opensource)

Comment: I can make a photo gallery in iOS but I only know how to do it locally.

Answer (score 4):

Download the list of images using the Flickr API, and asynchronously add them to a UIScrollView inside a UINavigationController with its back button as "back". Then add a UIToolBar which has the items 'Next' and 'Previous' (use images). That will give you the look of a photo gallery.

Also, I came across this which is basically what I told you to do, but open source: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/fgallery

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial on building a media gallery using a UICollectionView.  It populates from the user's photo library, but is definitely more extensible than using a 3rd party.

[iPhone Programming Tutorial: Creating An Image Gallery Like Over – Part 1](http://brandontreb.com/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-an-image-gallery-like-over-part-1)

Hope that helps. Cheers!